# Java servlet throws an exception when responding to a request with a file

Tags: java, html, exception, servlets

I'm pretty new to Java server applications. I'm trying to create a simple servlet returning an HTML file. I've tried with printing output from the servlet (the commented out part of the code below), which worked fine, but the file approach crashes immediately.
Below the code I've posted the exceptions I receive, however those aren't very descriptive neither to me nor Google.
Maybe it's some jar file I'm missing at some deployment stage?

@SOLVED: A couple of hours and pushup sets later I've found out '/' is not an acceptable suburl, changing to '/login' solved it.

File sctructure:

```
cache
-src
--cache
---LoginServlet.java
-WebContent
--META-INF  //autogenerated
--WEB-INF
---web.xml
--index.html
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package cache;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        /*PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();       
        out.print("asd");*/
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response); 
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>cache</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>cache.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

browser exception (repeated, I'm pasting only a single repetition)

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     cache.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:16)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

eclipse exception (repeated plenty of times)

> Jan 19, 2019 2:40:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Login] in context with
>   path [/cache] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception]
>   with root cause java.lang.StackOverflowError  at

this line is repeated a lot

> javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:408)
>   at

single unwrap

> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.unwrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:797)
>     at

and this repeated until the end

> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
>     at cache.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:16)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

@EDIT I've added a piece of stack trace I initially ignored as I hadn't seen the starting part of it, and I thought it was something concurrent.

Comment: There isn't a chain of "Caused by:" bits?

Comment: I've updated to exception stack trace. I didn't notice the beginning was printed, I thought it got overridden by the output.

Comment: The problem here is infinite recursion